# Barcodescanner phonegap, cordova.plugins is undefined

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Sounds familiar to what I found online, but I didn't get an answer to my case.

This is an Vue.js app, embedded in a cordova app, for Android.

I use Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova, and I installed plugins such as Camera, or phonegap's barcode scanner (installed in my project from [their github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)).

I got Camera plugin to work, with `navigator.camera.getPicture(callback)`.

It seems I should use phonegap's barcode scanner through `cordova` variable, with `cordova.plugins`, that's what is stated in their documentation, but this `cordova.plugins` is `undefined`.
People say plugins have to be accessed after the event `deviceready` fires, but even checking that, the event is indeed emitted, and just putting `console.log(cordova.plugins)` in the callback function, I get "undefined".

This is what I do

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
    console.log("The event is right !");
    console.log(cordova);
    console.log(cordova.plugins);
})
```

Everything is right except for the plugins (3rd log). `cordova.plugins` should be defined because I have some plugins that do use it, but it seems I'm doing something wrong... Maybe something about config.xml or package.json ?

Comment: Do you installed plugins manually or by some command?

Comment: This time I installed them through config.xml's Visual Studio, which offers a plugin manager tool, but I strongly think this is a beautiful version of `cordova plugin add <plugin>` command... I would say command then

Answer (score 0):

They changed something in new versions of this plagin, so it works only in new versions of Cordova as far as I undestand. So, my solution is to use old version of the plugin temporary. For instance, in this version of the plugin `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan` is available from a code on my side:

> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git#6.0.5

(you can see a version information at the end of this line)

Please let me know if you found better solution.